# How can I add a binary device driver in Platform Builder for Windows CE 6.0?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-ce, platform-builder

I need to add a device driver to a Windows CE image, I have the driver in .dll and .reg files and in a .cab package.
I'm using Visual Studio 2005 with Platform Builder for Windows CE 6.0.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you an OSDesign and you want to add the Dll to the image that the OSDesign creates, just put the Dll file in the %WinceRootDir%\Platform<yourPlatformName>\Files directory. If you do this, the file will be copied automatically to the release directory when you do a build. As for the registry, just add the relevant changes to the Porject.reg file and it will be integrated into the whole build. When you add a stream interface driver you need to add it's registry settings undet [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\BuiltIn\Drivers<NameOfYourDrvier>].
You can read here (An excellent Blog- [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20191229134051/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/BruceEitman/archive/2008/12/08/windows-ce-stream-interface-driver-registry-settings.aspx))  (I can't post another link so search msdn for the bus enumerator)  the necessary registry settings for a stream interface driver.

I have to say that the difficulties for new users with the posting restrictions are a real pain in the...

Hope this helps,

Shai

Comment: Thank you. 
Do you know if it's possible to do this as an independent Catalog Item instead of using global locations?

Comment: Read this entry in the same blog http://geekswithblogs.net/BruceEitman/archive/2008/06/20/platform-builder-6.0-creating-a-catalog-file.aspx. What are you aiming at exactly?